Old Mathematica Library folder
I'm trying to clear some space on my hard drive and found an appealing target for deletion. ~/Library/Mathematica takes up almost 6 GB of storage and seems unnecessary now that v14.1 creates ~/Library/Wolfram.


Safe to delete?

Backup then delete. If something failed then return back the backup.

@azerbajdzan Ha, that should have been obvious. Thanks!

Let us know if there was no problems after deleting.

In fact you do not need to delete or backup anything, just rename the folder to some other name. If there are no problems with Mathematica you can delete it. If Mathematica stops functioning properly rename the folder back to its original name.

They changed the language name from Mathematica to Wolfram to distinguish the language from the app. Are we going to have to change the language name again now that the app is called Wolfram? We could call it "NKC", the New Kind of Computation Language. Probably was already proposed the last time. And rejected.
